# Godunov's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods

Can anyone send me a link/refer me to some useful sources about Godunov's method? I need something simple and easy to understand, which doesn't require too much prior knowledge in PDE and associated models (suitable for a student with ODE level of knowledge, who knows a bit about PDE).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cannot find the original Godunov paper from the 50's translated from Russian to English, so here are two books I used to learn about the Godunov method.

Both books are written in the contexts of fluid dynamics but develop the general theory for solving PDEs on a computer at a level of mathematical rigor someone with basic calculus can understand.

1) "Computational Gasdynamics" by Laney. Here the idea of a conservative scheme is developed along with examples of different numerical fluxes including the Godunov method.

2) "Riemann Solvers and Numerical Methods for Fluid Dynamics: A Practical Introduction" by Toro. Shows many explicit example cases for you to test your implementation against.